# Flutter Firebase Project won't compile after 'pod update'

Tags: firebase, flutter, cocoapods

after I run pod update in my flutter project, my project won't compile for iOs. Thats what I already tried.

- Deleting the Pod Folder.
- Deleting the Podfile
- Running Pod init to create a new Podfile
- Paste the Code to the new Podfile and run Pod istall again.

  $ flutter doctor -v

  > [✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale de-DE)
  >       • Flutter version 1.2.1 at /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter
  >       • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (3 days ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
  >       • Engine revision 3757390fa4
  >       • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)
  >
  > [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
  >       • Android SDK at /Users/alexanderwilke/Library/Android/sdk
  >       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
  >       • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
  >       • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
  >       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
  >       • All Android licenses accepted.
  >
  > [✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
  >       • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
  >       • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
  >       • ios-deploy 1.9.4
  >       • CocoaPods version 1.6.0
  >
  > [✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
  >       • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
  >       • Flutter plugin version 32.0.1
  >       • Dart plugin version 182.5215
  >       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
  >
  > [✓] VS Code (version 1.31.1)
  >       • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
  >       • Flutter extension version 2.23.0
  >
  > [!] Connected device
  >       ! No devices available

---

```
Error Output:

Running pod install...                                              4,7s

> Xcode build done.                                            3,6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


> Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:29:50: warning: 'window' is only available on iOS 5.0 or newer
    [-Wunguarded-availability]
          [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
                                                     ^~~~~~
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mainuser/Documents/flutter_projects/firebaseProject/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:398:51: note: 'window' has been explicitly
    marked partial here
    @property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
                                                      ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:29:50: note: enclose 'window' in an @available check to silence this warning
          [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
                                                     ^~~~~~
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:79:45: warning: 'kUTTypeAVIMovie' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer
    [-Wunguarded-availability]
          (NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeAVIMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeVideo,
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'MobileCoreServices' imported from /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:7:
    In module 'CoreServices' imported from
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/Headers/MobileCoreServices.h:9:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/UTCoreTypes.h:892:26: note: 'kUTTypeAVIMovie' has been
    explicitly marked partial here
    extern const CFStringRef kUTTypeAVIMovie                             __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_10,__IPHONE_8_0);
                             ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:79:45: note: enclose 'kUTTypeAVIMovie' in an @available check to silence this
    warning
          (NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeAVIMovie, (NSString *)kUTTypeVideo,
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:111:22: warning: 'presentViewController:animated:completion:' is only available on
    iOS 5.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
        [_viewController presentViewController:_imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mainuser/Documents/flutter_projects/firebaseProject/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:227:1: note:
    'presentViewController:animated:completion:' has been explicitly marked partial here
    - (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^ __nullable)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
    ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:111:22: note: enclose 'presentViewController:animated:completion:' in an @available
    check to silence this warning
        [_viewController presentViewController:_imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:124:20: warning: 'presentViewController:animated:completion:' is only available on
    iOS 5.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
      [_viewController presentViewController:_imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mainuser/Documents/flutter_projects/firebaseProject/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:227:1: note:
    'presentViewController:animated:completion:' has been explicitly marked partial here
    - (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^ __nullable)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
    ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:124:20: note: enclose 'presentViewController:animated:completion:' in an @available
    check to silence this warning
      [_viewController presentViewController:_imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:131:27: warning: 'dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:' is only available on
    iOS 5.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
      [_imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mainuser/Documents/flutter_projects/firebaseProject/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:229:1: note:
    'dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:' has been explicitly marked partial here
    - (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^ __nullable)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
    ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:131:27: note: enclose 'dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:' in an @available
    check to silence this warning
      [_imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:185:27: warning: 'dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:' is only available on
    iOS 5.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
      [_imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mainuser/Documents/flutter_projects/firebaseProject/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/image_picker/image_picker-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:229:1: note:
    'dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:' has been explicitly marked partial here
    - (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated: (BOOL)flag completion: (void (^ __nullable)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
    ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.4.12+1/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m:185:27: note: enclose 'dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:' in an @available
    check to silence this warning
      [_imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    6 warnings generated.
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:4:8: error: unknown type name 'FIRVisionLabelDetector'; did you mean
    'FIRVisionFaceDetector'?
    static FIRVisionLabelDetector *detector;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           FIRVisionFaceDetector
    In module 'FirebaseMLVision' imported from /Users/mainuser/Documents/flutter_projects/firebaseProject/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:70:
    /Users/mainuser/Documents/flutter_projects/firebaseProject/ios/Pods/FirebaseMLVision/Frameworks/FirebaseMLVision.framework/Headers/FIRVisionFaceDetector.h:22:12: note: 'FIRVisionFaceDetector' declared here
    @interface FIRVisionFaceDetector : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:35:4: error: expected a type
    + (FIRVisionLabelDetectorOptions *)parseOptions:(NSDictionary *)optionsData {
       ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:10:22: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRVision' declares the selector
    'labelDetectorWithOptions:'
      detector = [vision labelDetectorWithOptions:[LabelDetector parseOptions:options]];
                  ~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:13:37: error: unknown type name 'FIRVisionLabel'; did you mean 'FIRVisionFace'?
                   completion:^(NSArray<FIRVisionLabel *> *_Nullable labels, NSError *_Nullable error) {
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                        FIRVisionFace
    In module 'FirebaseMLVision' imported from /Users/mainuser/Documents/flutter_projects/firebaseProject/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:70:
    /Users/mainuser/Documents/flutter_projects/firebaseProject/ios/Pods/FirebaseMLVision/Frameworks/FirebaseMLVision.framework/Headers/FIRVisionFaceDetector.h:3:8: note: 'FIRVisionFace' declared here
    @class FIRVisionFace;
           ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:22:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'FIRVisionLabel'
                     for (FIRVisionLabel *label in labels) {
                          ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:22:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'label'; did you mean 'labels'?
                     for (FIRVisionLabel *label in labels) {
                                          ^~~~~
                                          labels
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:13:66: note: 'labels' declared here
                   completion:^(NSArray<FIRVisionLabel *> *_Nullable labels, NSError *_Nullable error) {
                                                                     ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:24:40: error: use of undeclared identifier 'label'
                         @"confidence" : @(label.confidence),
                                           ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:25:36: error: use of undeclared identifier 'label'
                         @"entityID" : label.entityID,
                                       ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:26:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'label'
                         @"label" : label.label
                                    ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:12:13: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRVisionFaceDetector' declares the
    selector 'detectInImage:completion:'
      [detector detectInImage:image
       ~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:37:12: error: unknown receiver 'FIRVisionLabelDetectorOptions'; did you mean
    'FIRVisionFaceDetectorOptions'?
      return [[FIRVisionLabelDetectorOptions alloc] initWithConfidenceThreshold:[conf floatValue]];
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
               FIRVisionFaceDetectorOptions
    In module 'FirebaseMLVision' imported from /Users/mainuser/Documents/flutter_projects/firebaseProject/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Firebase/Firebase.h:70:
    /Users/mainuser/Documents/flutter_projects/firebaseProject/ios/Pods/FirebaseMLVision/Frameworks/FirebaseMLVision.framework/Headers/FIRVisionFaceDetectorOptions.h:72:12: note: 'FIRVisionFaceDetectorOptions'
    declared here
    @interface FIRVisionFaceDetectorOptions : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.2.1/ios/Classes/LabelDetector.m:37:49: error: no visible @interface for 'FIRVisionFaceDetectorOptions' declares the
    selector 'initWithConfidenceThreshold:'
      return [[FIRVisionLabelDetectorOptions alloc] initWithConfidenceThreshold:[conf floatValue]];
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    12 errors generated.
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.2.5+1/ios/Classes/FirebaseCorePlugin.m:13:17: warning: property 'dictionary' requires method 'dictionary' to be defined -
    use @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this category [-Wobjc-property-implementation]
    @implementation FIROptions (FLTFirebaseCorePlugin)
                    ^
    /Users/mainuser/Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.2.5+1/ios/Classes/FirebaseCorePlugin.m:10:46: note: property declared here
    @property(readonly, nonatomic) NSDictionary *dictionary;
                                                 ^
    1 warning generated.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**I fixed it by myself!**

Here is what I did:

1. Make a new Flutter project.
2. Copy all your files from `/lib` to the new project.
3. Delete `flutter/.pub-cache/hosted` in your `flutter` directory.
4. Copy the `pubspec.yaml` file into the new project.
5. Run `flutter packages get`.
6. Delete the Pod folder in your `PROJECT_DIR/ios` folder, the `Podfile.lock` and the `.workscape` file (or just run `pod clean` if you have the right cocoa pods version).
7. Go into the `PROJECT_DIR/ios` folder and run `pod install`.

That's it, your Flutter app should work again :)

Answer (score 5):

Solution by @Konrad worked perfectly, except that `pod clean` has been changed in the latest update to:

```
pod cache clean --all
```

Comment: Cleaning up furthermore is to wipe out the ios folder and then run from your root flutter folder:
```flutter create .```
More specific to iOS platform, run:
`flutter create . --platforms=ios`
as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66214067/1744410)

Answer (score 1):

You could try running a

```
flutter clean
```

I did a pod update to update the google maps sdk version and my ios project stopped working. Ran flutter clean and then tried running the app and it started working again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would also help someone `pod install --repo-update` this will update all the pods i.e. after upgrading flutter.