# How do I add Platforms to an Existing Flutter App/Project?

Tags: flutter

I created a Flutter app with mobile support only:

```sh
flutter create --platforms=ios,android foo
```

I also have another Flutter project that I created before web was supported by Flutter, which is why it only contains support for mobile.

---

Now, I want to run my app on web and macOS, but I receive the following error when trying to use `flutter run -d macos`:

```
Exception: No macOS desktop project configured. See https://flutter.dev/desktop#add-desktop-support-to-an-existing-app to learn about adding macOS support to a project.
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can add support for new plugins by **recreating** your project:

```sh
flutter create .
```

You can simply run this from the root of your Flutter project and it will add the required files for all platforms.

---

If you only want to add support for specific enabled platforms, you can do that by supplying the `--platforms` argument:

```sh
flutter create --platforms=web,macos .
```

Comment: I get the error `No option specified for the output directory.` when run `flutter create` or `flutter create --platforms web`. How to fix this?

Comment: @MuhammadQasim You need to add the `.` (which will create the project in the current directory) at the end of your command or specify an output directory.

Answer (score 11):

You can add web support to your flutter project by running the following line from your project terminal.

```
flutter create --platforms=web .
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add web support in your existing Flutter App using the below command.

```
flutter create --platforms web .
```

It we generate all the necessary file require for web. After that you can run the App in chrome using below command.

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

Answer (score 2):

To add Linux platform run this command line:

```bash
flutter create --platforms=linux .
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are still facing this issue after trying the above steps.
Ensure to put the  `.` at the end of the code you type in terminal.
So, `flutter create --platforms=linux .` or whatever platform you choose.

Answer (score 0):

For eg. if you want to enable macos to your project, this is what you should do.

1. flutter config --enable-macos-desktop
2. flutter create .