# How to add or remove supported platform from a published package on pub.dev for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have published a package on pub.dev that only supported android initial and now I want to support other platforms such macOs, iOS and Web. I do not see where to specify the platforms in the pubspec.yaml file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After few weeks of searching, I finally found the documentation to specify the platforms in the pubspec.yaml file

```yaml
# This package supports all platforms listed below.
platforms:
  android:
  ios:
  linux:
  macos:
  web:
  windows:
```

read more: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec#platforms

Answer (score 0):

You can find your answer here:
[How do I add Platforms to an Existing Flutter App/Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214066/how-do-i-add-platforms-to-an-existing-flutter-app-project)

After you create platform folders, pub.dev will display which platforms your plugin supports.

Comment: The answer above is for a Flutter Project not a package, when I run the command It throws an error : The "--platforms" argument is not supported in package template.

Comment: no need, just type: `flutter create .`

Comment: bro, you need to type as answer, not like the question :)

Comment: how's it going? @DingaanLetjane