# Not able to find xcode project while running pod install

Tags: flutter, xcode, podfile

When I am trying to build my Xcode is saying:

> The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

As a result I am trying to run `pod install` but getting:

> `ios % pod install Analyzing dependencies [!] Unable to find the Xcode project '/Users/user/Documents/GitHub/samples/changers/ios/Runner.xcodeproj' for the target 'Pods-Runner'.`

I tried different things that had been posted here, but so far nothing worked.

Thank you for any help with that!

Comment: open ios folder with Finder. Do u see anything like Runner.xcodeproj & Runner.xcworkspace

Comment: I have only .xcworkspace

Answer (score 1):

Oh, so do you get it? Maybe some unwanted actions make your xcodeproj disappear. If you haven't modified any inside iOS native code, you can delete entire ios folder and create it again. Checkout this: [How do I add Platforms to an Existing Flutter App/Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214066/how-do-i-add-platforms-to-an-existing-flutter-app-project) . Or short: type `flutter create .`

Answer (score 1):

`cd ios`

`rm -rf Podfile.lock`

`arch -x86_64 pod install --repo-update`

Try using these codes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something happened with paths to my directory with xcode project, so when I changed flag to `$(inherited)` flag and run pod install everything worked fine.